# How to separate string to more than one part C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string, that contains links. Example:

```
www.google.com;www.yahoo.com;www.gmail.com
```

My question is how can I separate those links so I can add to all the links the tag `<a>` and in the end of the link the tag `</a>`?

I should get this:

```
<a>www.google.com</a>;<a>www.yahoo.com</a>;<a>www.gmail.com</a>
```

I will be thankful if the solution will be simple as possible and use the `IndexOf` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code should do the job:

```
var input = "www.google.com;www.yahoo.com;www.gmail.com";
var result = string.Join(";", input.Split(';').Select(x => string.Format("<a>{0}</a>",x)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But can you explain pleas what this code does?

Comment: 1. Split your string by ';' caracter  
2. Wrap each element in <a></a>
3. Join resulted elements, separating them by ';'

Answer (score 3):

```
var links = "www.google.com;www.yahoo.com;www.gmail.com";
var result = String.Join(";", links.Split(';').Select(s => String.Format("<a>{0}</a>", s)));
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```
var result = "<a>" + String.Join("</a>;<a>", input.Split(new char[] { ';' })) + "</a>";
```

However, it will return `<a></a>` for empty input.

Explanation:

`input.Split(new char[] { ';' })` splits input string by `:` character.

`String.Join("</a>;<a>", input.Split(new char[] { ';' }))` joins elements from the split using `</a>;<a>` string.

`"<a>" + String.Join("</a>;<a>", input.Split(new char[] { ';' })) + "</a>";` adds additional `<a>` in front and `</a>` at the end of results.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great! But can you explain this code? (I'm learning C# now and don't know every thing in this language...)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var result = String.Join(";", 
"www.google.com;www.yahoo.com;www.gmail.com"
.Split(';')
.Select(str => String.Format("<a>{0}</a>", str)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use split() function . Split string by character ; and store in an array.

```
string[] arr = inputstring.Split(';'); 
string outputstring=string.Empty;
for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
  outputstring += "<a>"+arr[i]+"</a>;";
```

Since you don't want semicolon at end

`outputstring = outputstring .TrimEnd(';');`